# Wagon getting stuck in mud

Tags: talmud-gemara, story-identification

Is there some story in the Gemara or something where this wagoner has his cart get stuck in mud? Very vague but do any stories ring a bell?

Comment: Does he have very fancy horses that don't work together well and is rescued by a team of weak horses that do cooperate?

Comment: Does he ask the Baal Shem Tov's students for assistance and they say they're unable to help and the Besht says "you can, but you don't want to"?

Comment: No not any of those. Idk maybe I made it up

Comment: Any more details you can add will help others to help you.

Comment: Not in the gemara.

Comment: Is he riding with his family and they all get saved by a miserly rich man?

Comment: Was he helped by a sinful man who was redeemed by the weight of the wagon and the mud on the heavenly scales?

Comment: I've heard all of the above, and I think there's another one, possibly in Rav Ovadia Yosef's collection on Pirkei Avot

Comment: @shmosel can you send that one please

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3833365/jewish/The-Muddy-Path-to-Paradise.htm